# How to Send Bulk Emails via Phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have one website. In which I have to send emails in bulk. Like 3,000-4,000 emails per hour. I am using Siteground Cloud Server. But it's not able to send emails this much quickly.

So can anyone suggest me any way to send bulk emails via **PHPMailer** without getting them in queue.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: the world is so tired of spam and spammers.  is 3,000 emails per hour just not enough?

Comment: Hey It's not spam. It's kind of viral website which send emails to users when they enter email.

Comment: I wounder if any way to send emails fast. like by using multiple smtp accounts?

Comment: You really need to talk to your service provider - you don't want to get yourself black listed, or your provider.  That said, PHPMailer may not be the tool for such mass quantities in a short time period

Comment: the question is too broad and there are related questions already asked here on Stack; you need to look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is indeed too broad, so you're only going to get vague answers.

You should at least look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), as that deals with the basics. PHPMailer is perfectly capable of high speeds - I have no trouble getting ~250 messages *per second* using it.

It helps to have a very cosy relationship with your mail server too - many open source ones are either not up to the job or are hard to configure, but 4,000/hour is a tiny amount in the scheme of things and default configs can work.

You need to have absolutely solid SPF, DKIM and DMARC configs, plus hypersensitive bounce handling (remailing a previously bouncing address on yahoo can get you blocked for ages).

Technical steps aside, it will take you a while to build up a sending reputation no matter what you do, and the behaviour of many large ISPs is pretty bad. For example I have a community site with several thousand members on hotmail, and occasionally one of them reports a notification as spam (it's all just forum traffic, no mailshots) - this results in the entire site being blacklisted and spamboxed for *every* hotmail member for about 2 months. Really not very clever or helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer